# Can I tell the Closure compiler to, for specific types only, stop renaming properties?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

This question follows: [Why does Closure compiler rename properties of an extern type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196243/why-does-closure-compiler-rename-properties-of-an-extern-type/8198809#8198809)  John's answer to that question brings up this second question.

If I declare the extern type as suggested:

```
/** @interface */
function SpanishNoun() {}
/** @type {string} */
SpanishNoun.prototype.english;
/** @type {string} */
SpanishNoun.prototype.spanish;
```

then Javascript like:

```
/**
 * @param {SpanishNoun} n 
 */
exp.foo = function (n) {
    console.log(n.english, n.spanish, n['english'], n['spanish']);  
}
```

will compile, as desired, to:

```
function(a){console.log(a.english,a.spanish,a.english,a.spanish)};
```

The properties are not renamed as usual.  Without the extern declaration, the compiled code would look like:

```
function(a){console.log(a.a,a.c,a.english,a.spanish)
```

That's all good.  The problem is that the compiler has stopped renaming 'english' and 'spanish' in *all* places.  Even if they are not on the extern type.

```
/**
 * @param {AnotherType}  
 */
exp.bar = function (c) {
    c.other = c.english;
}
```

compiles to...

```
function(a){a.b=a.english};
```

Is there a way to stop this?  If not, is there a reason for this behavior?

I wanted to use extern types to handle things like JSON objects that originate from the server and do not have renamed properties.  But if every time I declare an extern I'm eating away at the compiler's ability to rename and shrink the code, I will find another way.  Perhaps I will take the property renaming map generated by the compiler (`--property_map_output_file`) and use it on the server when generating JSON responses.

Comment: This is the standard behavior of Closure in order to avoid bugs (you can read the Closure web site to understand why this is necessary). Closure always renames the same property name to the same mangled name. On the flip side, it does not rename all properties (regardless of where) of the same name -- because in essence non-renaming is just renaming to itself. There is a flag (called `ambiguateProperties` or something like that) that you can turn on the avoid this, but it is experimental only.

Comment: The reason for this standard behavior is that you can write a function that just takes an object, and use the `english` property on that object.  Closure has no way to know what object you're passing in, and whether that object's `english` property has been renamed or not.  Because JavaScript is a non-typed language, you can do this kind of things (by passing in different objects of different classes), so the compiler must rename the same property name to the same string to avoid not being able to decide which version of the name it is mapped to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Closure Compiler can rename based on types: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Type-Based-Property-Renaming
This enhances other optimizations such as inlining and dead code removal as well.  This is used internally to Google but comes with a cost as it can introduce some hard debug scenarios if you "lie" in your type declarations.

Comment: That link no longer works. Maybe this is new (no longer experimental) link: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Type-Based-Property-Renaming