# Exposing dynamically created functions on objects with closure compiler

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I am trying to annotate my javascript so that closure doesnt rename all the symbols since i am working with vanilla javascript as well.

```
/**
* @constructor
* @expose
* @type{foo}
*/

foo = function (el, args) {
"use strict";
var s = "Hello World";
/*
* @expose
* @this {foo}
* @type {function}
*/
this.introduce = function () {
    return s;
 };
};
```

However the generated output when i run it through the closure compiler with advanced optimization is

```
foo = function() {
 this.a = function() {
 return"Hello World"
```

}
 };

How do i ask closure to preserve the name introduce since this will be called from an external javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following options may be used to prevent the Closure Compiler from renaming
symbols:

- [`@export`](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) (also see: [`goog.exportSymbol`](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/closure/goog/base.js?spec=svn60ec04c13f5c3f9b471fb1c3eb6b5588670aeb99&r=60ec04c13f5c3f9b471fb1c3eb6b5588670aeb99#1447) or [`goog.exportProperty`](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/closure/goog/base.js?spec=svn60ec04c13f5c3f9b471fb1c3eb6b5588670aeb99&r=60ec04c13f5c3f9b471fb1c3eb6b5588670aeb99#1476))
- Export symbols by storing them on the global object referenced by a string.
  See [Export the Symbols You Want to Keep](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#export)
- Define an interface in an externs file and implement the interface (see linked answers below)
- Quote properties
- **Note:** `@expose` has been deprecated

If you do not want to define methods on the function prototype as shown in your
example, then you could export the constructor `foo` with `goog.exportSymbol`
 and use `@expose` to export methods.

```js
/**
 * @param {Element} el
 * @param {...*} args
 * @constructor
 */
var foo = function (el, args) {
  "use strict";

  /** @private */
  this.msg_ = "Hello World";

  /**
   * @this {foo}
   * @return {string}
   * @expose
   */
  this.introduce = function () {
    return this.msg_;
  };
};
goog.exportSymbol('foo', foo);
```

By defining methods on the function prototype, `goog.exportSymbol` can be
used to export both the constructor as well as method names.

```js
/**
 * @param {Element} el
 * @param {...*} args
 * @constructor
 */
var foo = function (el, args) {
  "use strict";

  /** @private */
  this.msg_ = 'Hello World!';
};
goog.exportSymbol('foo', foo);

/**
 * @return {string}
 */
foo.prototype.introduce = function () {
  return this.msg_;
};
goog.exportSymbol('foo.prototype.introduce', foo.prototype.introduce);
```

See these related stackoverflow questions:

- **[Why does Closure compiler rename properties of an extern type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8196243/1164465)**
- **[Can I tell the Closure compiler to, for specific types only,
  stop renaming properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8201954/1164465)**
- [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9662283/1164465) to the question: **How to tell Closure Compiler to
  preserve properties on an object**

Comment: When i use the @expose annotation on the prototype methods,it works fine without having to use goog.exportSymbol. However the expose annotation doesnt seem to work on functions being added directly to the object rather than the prototype. I would like to use it in the former case so that i can use closures instead of trying to have member variables all over.

Comment: Answer updated to explain @expose and provide working examples using methods defined directly on the constructor as well as the function prototype.

Comment: Don't use @expose annotation. It's brittle. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/closure-compiler-discuss/B_WpQgpaoKw/4GZyCCTL4nQJ

Comment: `@expose` is now deprecated. It is replaced by `@nocollapse` and `@export`. The compiler will warn about any usage of `@expose`.