# Module pattern with Closure Compiler and ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS

Tags: javascript, module, google-closure-compiler

I am aware that similar questions have been asked before, but methodology changes quickly so I'm seeking to understand current best practices. (In fact, as recently as 2 days ago, Chad Killingsworth added a comment to an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681070/exposing-dynamically-created-functions-on-objects-with-closure-compiler) from three years ago that `@expose` annotation is now deprecated.)

I'm using the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html). Working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tzc22e5u/2/) of the below code:

```
/** @const */
var MATHCALCS = (function () {
    'use strict';

    var MY = {};

    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {!Object} obj
     * @expose
     */
    MY.ModuleStruct = function (obj) {
        /** @expose */
        this.color = (obj.color !== undefined) ? obj.color : null;
        /** @expose */
        this.size = (obj.size !== undefined) ? obj.size : null;
    };

    /**
     * @expose
     */
    MY.ModuleStruct.prototype.clone = function () {
        return new MY.ModuleStruct({
            "color": this.color,
                "size": this.size
        });
    };


    MY.moduleProperty = 1;

    /**
     * @type {function(!Array<number>)}
     * @expose
     */
    MY.moduleMethod = function (a) {
        var i, x = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
            x = x + a[i];
        }
        return x;
    };

    return MY;

}());

window["MATHCALCS"] = MATHCALCS;*
```

Currently, using `@expose` annotation, above can be minified with Closure in advance mode and the following calls work ([minified example](http://jsfiddle.net/duc88xLr/2/)):

```
// call a public method
alert(MATHCALCS.moduleMethod([1, 2, 3]));

// allocate a new structure
var ms = new MATHCALCS.ModuleStruct({
    "color": "red",
        "size": "small"
});
alert(ms.color + '\t' + ms.size);

// clone a second instance
var ms2 = ms.clone();
alert(ms2.color + '\t' + ms2.size);
alert(ms !== ms2); // cloned objs are not equal

// and directly update the properties of the object
ms2.color = "white";
ms2.size = "large";
alert(ms2.color + '\t' + ms2.size);
```

If possible, without changing away from the module pattern, I would like to update code (approx 10,000 lines) to use `@export` annotation. However, when I replace `@expose` with `@export` Closure raises this error:

> ERROR - @export only applies to symbols/properties defined in the global scope.

**Q:** Is it possible, and if so, how should the above code be annotated to work with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS?

I am aware that I can possibly use this type of notation:

```
MY["ModuleStruct"] = MY.ModuleStruct;
MY["ModuleStruct"]["prototype"]["clone"] = MY.ModuleStruct.prototype.clone;
```

but exporting object properties this way will become tedious. Further JSLint complains about weird assignments so I would rather use JSDocs annotation.

Comment: `@export` is the correct method. It looks like we'll need to do some work on it to support this type of use case.

Comment: Issue added https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/912

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth, thanks for raising the issue ticket. It would be great if support for the `@expose` notation is not removed until `@export` supports this pattern for `@expose` is currently working fine for this case.

Comment: `@expose` support won't be removed from the compiler for quite some time. However, warnings will now be issued about it's use. I'm going to be working on improvements for `@export` soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until [the issue raised by @ChadKillingsworth](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/912) is resolved, here's a solution which will enable you to use `@export` with only minor modifications to your code:

```
/** @const */
var MATHCALCS = {};

goog.scope(function () {
    'use strict';

    var MY = MATHCALCS;

    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {!Object} obj
     * @export
     */
    MY.ModuleStruct = function (obj) {
        this.color = (obj.color !== undefined) ? obj.color : null;
        this.size = (obj.size !== undefined) ? obj.size : null;
    };

    /**
     * @export
     */
    MY.ModuleStruct.prototype.clone = function () {
        return new MY.ModuleStruct({
            "color": this.color,
                "size": this.size
        });
    };


    MY.moduleProperty = 1;

    /**
     * @type {function(!Array<number>)}
     * @export
     */
    MY.moduleMethod = function (a) {
        var i, x = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
            x = x + a[i];
        }
        return x;
    };

});
```

The changes are:

- Change the `@expose` tags to `@export`.
- Create an empty `MATHCALCS` object outside the module wrapper function, and make the `MY` alias point to it.
- Instead of executing the module wrapper function immediately (IIFE), pass it to [`goog.scope()`](http://google.github.io/closure-library/api/namespace_goog.html#scope). This enables aliasing within scope functions, allowing the compiler to work out that the exported symbols are being defined on the global `MATHCALCS` object. This prevents the compiler from raising the error ("`@export` only applies to symbols/properties defined in the global scope").
- Remove the following items, which are not needed:

  - The `@export` tags on `this.color` and `this.size`
  - `return MY;`
  - `window["MATHCALCS"] = MATHCALCS;`

When compiled with this command:

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
    --js closure/goog/base.js \
    --js mathcalcs.js \
    --js_output_file mathcalcs.min.js \
    --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
    --generate_exports \
    --formatting PRETTY_PRINT \
    --output_wrapper '(function() {%output%}).call(window);'
```

you'll get:

```
(function() {var f = this;
function g(a, d) {
  var b = a.split("."), c = f;
  b[0] in c || !c.execScript || c.execScript("var " + b[0]);
  for (var e;b.length && (e = b.shift());) {
    b.length || void 0 === d ? c[e] ? c = c[e] : c = c[e] = {} : c[e] = d;
  }
}
;function h(a) {
  this.color = void 0 !== a.color ? a.color : null;
  this.size = void 0 !== a.size ? a.size : null;
}
g("MATHCALCS.ModuleStruct", h);
h.prototype.clone = function() {
  return new h({color:this.color, size:this.size});
};
h.prototype.clone = h.prototype.clone;
g("MATHCALCS.moduleMethod", function(a) {
  var d, b = 0;
  for (d = 0;d < a.length;d += 1) {
    b += a[d];
  }
  return b;
});
}).call(window);
```

The `g()` function is the compiled version of [`goog.exportSymbol()`](http://google.github.io/closure-library/api/namespace_goog.html#exportSymbol) – see [the `@export` docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#tag-export) for more details.

Note: if you want to run the code uncompiled, you'll need to load the Closure Library, or define `goog.scope()` yourself:

```
var goog = {};
goog.scope = function(fn) {
    fn();
};
```

Here's [a fork of your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngf6p20b/2/) with all these changes.